# jmeter: Error invoking bsh method: in Beanshell Postprocessor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a BeanShell postprocessor which has the below code:

```
props.put("accDom",vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1"));
```

Although the code works, and the value does get written to the defined property correctly, the log file is filled with such errors:

```
2020-11-24 14:41:19,655 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval     Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``props.put("accDom",vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1"));'' : Method Invocation props.put
2020-11-24 14:41:19,655 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval      Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``props.put("accDom",vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1"));'' : Method Invocation props.put
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I modified the script to use this:

```
String accDom = vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1");
props.put("accDom",accDom);
```

But still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the BeanShell PostProcessor to a JSR223 Sampler, and edited the syntax to:

```
String accDom = vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1");
props.put("accDom",accDom);

// Hide sampler
SampleResult.setIgnore();
```

This stopped all errors in the logs

Answer (score 0):

The log entry doesn't tell the full story, my expectation is that your `DOMAIN_ID_1` variable is `null` at some point, you can try surrounding your code into [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    props.put("accDom", vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1"));
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Failure", ex);
}
```

this way you will get more comprehensive [stacktrace](https://stackify.com/java-stack-trace/) in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so:

1. Change your Beanshell PostProcessor to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)
2. Amend your code to use [Elvis operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator) to provide the default value if  `DOMAIN_ID_1` variable is not set:

   ```
   props.put("accDom", vars.get("DOMAIN_ID_1") ?: "some default value");
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

And last but not the least, it might be the case your PostProcessor placement causes its extra execution, see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) chapter for detailed explanation, you should put the PostProcessor as a child of the Sampler which defines this `DOMAIN_ID_1` variable, if you place it at the same level with all the Samplers - it will be executed **after each sampler** causing errors as the variable is not defined.

Comment: Thanks. I tried catching the exception, but that did not give me more information. You are right when you say that the variable was null at some point, which it is at the start of the script. For now, defining a JSR223 sampler vis-a-vis a beanshell postprocessor has solved my issue, but i will try the postprocessor as a child option. Thanks!